# How android detect button positions and call appropriate handler?

Tags: java, android, operating-system, touch, system

I know this may not be an appropriate question, but I want to know how a touch enabled OS like
android detects a button in an app and calls the appropriate handler? When programming an app we just give the alignment information of a particular button. So, how android keeps the mapping between a button and screen position? I think this is kindof dynamic because if you change the screen orientation or use zoom or something like that the button positions are changed dynamically. So, android must look at the touch position and decide whether a button is there or not and call the appropriate handler. How this all things put together?

I appreciate any reply.